# Find all $z$ such that $iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\le 0$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

The square root is defined as follows:
$$z=re^{i\theta},\, -\pi\lt \theta\le \pi,\, \sqrt{z}=\sqrt{r}e^{\frac{1}{2}i\theta},\, \sqrt{r}\ge 0.$$

I'm trying to find all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that

$$iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\le 0.$$

This implies that we must also have $\operatorname{Im}(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2})=0$. I started like this:

$$\begin{align}iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}&=i(a+bi)+\sqrt{1-(a+bi)^2}\\&=ia-b+\sqrt{1-a^2+b^2-2abi}\\&=ia-b+\sqrt[4]{(1-a^2+b^2)^2+4a^2b^2}e^{\frac{i}{2}\operatorname{Arg}(1-a^2+b^2-2abi)}.\end{align}$$

Now I assumed that $1-a^2+b^2\gt 0$, so I lost some generality:

$$iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}=ia-b+\sqrt[4]{(1-a^2+b^2)^2+4a^2b^2}e^{-\frac{i}{2}\arctan \frac{2ab}{1-a^2+b^2}}.$$

I took the real part:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{Re}(iz+\sqrt{1-z^2})&=-b+\sqrt[4]{(1-a^2+b^2)^2+4a^2b^2}\cos\frac{1}{2}\arctan \frac{2ab}{1-a^2+b^2}\\&=-b+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt[4]{(1-a^2+b^2)^2+4a^2b^2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{4a^2b^2}{(1-a^2+b^2)^2}+1}}+1}.\end{align}$$

So we must also have
$$-b+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt[4]{(1-a^2+b^2)^2+4a^2b^2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{4a^2b^2}{(1-a^2+b^2)^2}+1}}+1}\le 0.$$

It seems that this made the problem even more complicated...

Comment: What does $\le$ mean for complex numbers? The field of complex numbers can’t be ordered.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net If $f(z)\le m$, then $\operatorname{Im}f(z)=0$. It's already written in the post.

Comment: Writing inequalities for complex numbers is misleading. If I understand well, you want the imaginary part to vanish and then the real par to be non negative. You should update your question accordingly.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net There's no need to do that. If $iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\in\mathbb{R}$, we can establish inequalities. If $iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$, we don't establish inequalities. There's no ambiguity at all.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $z\lt 0$ is equivalent to the fact that $z$ lies on the negative real axis in the complex plane. Where's the problem?

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain?

Comment: *$<0$ is equivalent to the fact that $z$
 lies on the negative real axis in the complex plan* is **your definition** of the $<$ sign for complex numbers. You should explicitely mention it in your question.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I don't think it's "my definition". $z\lt 0$ automatically implies that $z$ is some real number.

Comment: We can restate this as $e^{i\arcsin z}\le0$, i.e. $\Re\arcsin z\in\pi\Bbb Z\setminus2\pi\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would interpret $c \leq 0$ as $c \in (-\infty, -0]$ for complex numbers $c$.

Hint: There exist $t$ real such that $iz+\sqrt {1-z^{2}} =t$. This can be written as $\frac {(iz)^{2}-(1-z^{2})} {iz-\sqrt {1-z^{2}} } =t$ or $iz-\sqrt {1-z^{2}} =-\frac  1 t$. Add this to the  original equation  to see that $2iz$ is real. Hence $z$ is purely imaginary. Can you finish?

Comment: Hmm, if I set $z=i$, then I get $iz+\sqrt{1-z^2}=\sqrt{2}-1$, which is greater than $0$...

Comment: @BIRA I did not say that every purely imaginary number $z$ satisfies the given  inequality. I proved that $z$ must be purely imaginary. Now take $z=is$ where $s$ is real and plug that into the given inequality. It is your job  now  to solve the inequality and see what values of $s$ are permissible.

Comment: I see... Thanks.